# Ad-Hoc Wi-FI interface wireless channel

Tags: wifi, ad-hoc-network

I've been trying to get my machine to work with Wi-Fi Direct and also ad-hoc mode. I have two dongles, one for each mode. I'm following this tutorial on how to set up wifi ad-hoc: [WiFi Ad-hoc Network](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/AdHoc)

*edit*

I followed the following steps:

I modified the `/etc/network/interfaces` document to be the following:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid IBSSNetwork
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

`wlan0` was my adapter for IBSS mode and `wlan1` is my adapter for Wi-Fi direct. I also enabled Wi-Fi direct in the wpa_supplicant configuration. My other computer that I'm trying to communicate with using ad-hoc had the following in the `/etc/network/interfaces` document:

```
 auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.31
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid IBSSNetwork
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

From this configuration, I can ping each computer but I cannot create a Wi-Fi direct network. Now I change the `/etc/network/interfaces` document to be

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 7
    wireless-essid IBSSNetwork
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

and

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.2.31
netmask 255.255.255.0
wireless-channel 7
wireless-essid IBSSNetwork
wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

and after rebooting the computer, I can no longer communicate via ad-hoc between computers, but I can create a Wi-Fi direct network on my first computer.

*end edit*

And I'm able to get the Wi-Fi direct and Wi-Fi ad hoc to work independently but not simultaneously. Here's my problem:

When I follow the guide and set the wireless channel to 1 and I use `wpa_cli` - the `p2p-dev-wlan1` interface does not show up. When I change the wireless channel in the `/etc/network/interfaces` document, I can't ping the other computer on the Ad-hoc network.

**So my question is, what is blocking me from using both interfaces simultaneously and why can't I set the Wi-Fi ad hoc network to another channel and still communicate with other devices?**

Thanks!

Comment: Please detail exactly what you have done instead of linking tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

"Ad-hoc mode" (also called IBSS, *Independent Basic Service Set*) and "WiFi Direct" (also called Wifi P2P, *Point To Point*) or two totally different modes of operation. If you have a look at the capabilities of your WiFi card(s) with `iw phy`, you'll see both listed under "supported interface modes" (`IBBS` and several variants of `P2P-*`).

So they don't have anything to do with each other, and using either of them is enough for your computers to communicate. You don't need both.

That said, many current network cards support *multiple* interface modes at the same time. If you scroll down a bit in the output of `iw phy`, you'll see "valid interface combinations", and very likely at least one of your cards support a combination of IBSS and P2P at the same time.

So the first step is to verify that indeed *both* computers allow you to do this (edit your question with the output in this section for both computers if you don't understand how to read the output).

If only one of your computer supports it, and the other doesn't, then there's no way you can use both IBSS and P2P at the same time with this setup, period. (And as said above, you don't need to, if your goal is just to communicate between both computers).

And if in addition to your Wifi experiments you are also connected via managed mode to your usual access point (home router etc.), you even have three concurrent active modes, and probably channel restrictions on those. So in that case you need to have a closer look at what channel combinations are allowed.

TL;DR: What's blocking your experiment are hardware restrictions on the simultanious interface modes. See what is possible on your hardware, and only attempt to do what is possible, and it should work.